# Round Robin Scheduling

Tags: operating-system

I have a question here about round-robin and I was wondering if this answer is correct(it is the dr.'s answer).

We are supposed to get the average turnaround time of the processes who all come at same time which came in order as in the picture, it uses round robin with quantum of 5 seconds

[image]

Given answer was like that

[image]

But I think there are some extra counted time in there so my answer is like that

(26+27+12+16+30) / 5 = 22.2

I was wondering which one is correct, in my answer I tracked each process got its finish time and subtracted from start time which is 0 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the question given, the correct answer is 22.2